# Table values as input for a SQL function

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle11g, google-bigquery

I am trying to use all the values of a table as an input for an SQL defined function.

```
SELECT Field1,  REGEXP_CONTAINS(Field1, (SELECT Field2 FROM table2)) FROM table1;
```

This one returns an error in big query because:

1. the sub-query can't be used as an input and
2. it's returning more than 1 row.

Can you please tell me if there is a way to use all the values of one table as an input for a single function.

Best regards,

Comment: This question has tags for 4 different database engines - which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `CROSS JOIN` instead. Note that this will be slow if the tables are large, since you're taking the cross product of all the rows:

```
SELECT
  t1.Field1,
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(t1.Field1, t2.Field2)
FROM table1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN table2 AS t2;
```

If you want to know all of the `Field1`/`Field2` pairs for which this expression is true, you can use a query with a filter:

```
SELECT
  t1.Field1,
  t2.Field2
FROM table1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN table2 AS t2
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(t1.Field1, t2.Field2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  Field1, STRING_AGG(Field2) AS contained
FROM `table1`
JOIN `table2`
ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(Field1, Field2) 
GROUP BY Field1
```

you can test / play with above using below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table1` AS (
  SELECT 'abc' Field1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz'
),
`table2` AS (
  SELECT 'a' Field2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'z'
)
SELECT 
  Field1, STRING_AGG(Field2) AS contained
FROM `table1`
JOIN `table2`
ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(Field1, Field2) 
GROUP BY Field1
```

with result as

```sql
Field1  contained    
abc     a    
xyz     x,y,z
```

> Second Option is more inline with your original expectation (in terms
>   of syntax pattern) but requires use of [`SQL UDF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#sql-udf-structure):

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Check_Contains(str STRING, arr ARRAY<STRING>) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(item) AS contained
  FROM UNNEST(arr) item
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, item) 
));
SELECT Field1, 
  Check_Contains(Field1, ARRAY(SELECT Field2 FROM `table2`)) AS contained
FROM `table1`
```

To test / play  - you can use below

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Check_Contains(str STRING, arr ARRAY<STRING>) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(item) AS contained
  FROM UNNEST(arr) item
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, item) 
));
WITH `table1` AS (
  SELECT 'abc' Field1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'vwu'
),
`table2` AS (
  SELECT 'a' Field2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'z'
)
SELECT Field1, 
  Check_Contains(Field1, ARRAY(SELECT Field2 FROM `table2`)) AS contained
FROM `table1`
```

with output as

```sql
Field1  contained    
abc     a    
xyz     x,y,z    
vwu     null
```

> One more option (without UDF)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT Field1, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Field1, (SELECT STRING_AGG(Field2, '|') FROM `table2`)), ',') AS contained
FROM `table1`
```

you can use same dummy data as for above (first two options)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. 
I have a similar version to big query and ended up using the following code which is close to your suggestions.

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT field1 FROM UNNEST(['value1', ...'value2']) AS field1),
table2 AS (SELECT field2 FROM UNNEST(['v1', 'v2']) AS field2)
SELECT
field1,
(SELECT LOGICAL_OR(REGEXP_CONTAINS(field1, CONCAT(r'(?i)\b', field2, r'\b'))) FROM table2) AS has_table2_match
FROM
table1
```

Thank you again for your suggestions. Appreciate it.